# Programmatically do something when a node is updated

Tags: 8, hooks

I want to do something when a node gets updated. To keep it simple, lets say display a drupal message.

**hello_world.routing.yml**

```
hello_world:
    path: /node/{node}
    defaults:
        _controller: Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloWorldController::hello_world_entity_update
    requirements:
        _permission: 'access content'
```

Not sure if the path should be `/node/{node}/edit` instead.

**HelloWorldController.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloController.
 */

namespace Drupal\hello_world\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class HelloWorldController extends ControllerBase {

  public function hello_world_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) { 
     
    drupal_set_message(t('Something @var just happened.', array('@var' => 'cool')));  
      
  }
}
```

Since hook_node_update() was depreciated, I assume we now have to use hook_entity_update().

I am not getting the message upon updating a node, what I'm I missing or doing wrong?

---

#### Update

> Just so I don't confuse anyone.
> I was brainwashed into thinking I needed a routing file and a
> controller. All the D8 examples out there use them.
>
> **Since I was not creating any pages**,
> turns out **I did not need a routing.yml file nor a Controller.php file**
> nor the /src folder. All I had to do is approach this like Drupal 7,
> all that I needed was the .info.yml file and a .module file
> to put the hook.

Comment: You have to put hook_entity_update() in helloword.module. This does not work as a controller.

Comment: Thank you for the disclaimer at the end.  I'm a D7 veteran but new to D8 and I'm still trying to figure out when to use the OOP structure... all the documentation says how to use it, but not when...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hooks are still implemented as global, procedural functions; you need to declare them in the .module file just like Drupal 7, not in a controller class:

```
function MYMODULE_entity_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  // ...
}
```

It's also worth noting that [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/8.2.x) also exists, so you can still use `hook_node_update()`:

```
function MYMODULE_node_update(Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: interesting, then what should I put in my controller? controllers are not mandatory?

Comment: Typically a controller is linked up to a route, so they're generally used for building the markup (render array) for a page

Comment: `so they're generally used for building the markup (render array) for a page` since I am not building a page, leave the controller class empty? or delete it all together?

Comment: Are you thinking a module requires a controller? It doesn't, so unless you need it for something (essentially building a page), just remove the file

Comment: [according to this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643) I need to have something for `defaults:` in my hello_world.rounting.yml, so what should I use instead? `_entity_form`?

Comment: What's that routing entry for exactly? You might just be thinking about this too hard, to do something when a node is updated all you need is a single hook. There's no routing involved

Comment: says here  "[defaults (required):](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643)"

Comment: Yep, defaults are required for a route. But why do you need a route? What's it for? What are you routing to where and why?

Comment: ah ok gotcha!!! no I am not routing anything, so I will delete the defaults part all together. I couldn't find any D8 example out there that did something without creating a page.

Comment: Sounds like you can just delete the routing file altogether unless there's something else in it :)

Comment: OMG that's even better!

Answer (score 3):

1. You need not define any controller for this .
2. Write this code in your custom .module file.

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

```
 function module_name_entity_update(EntityInterface $entity) { 

    drupal_set_message(t('Something @var just happened.', array('@var' => 'cool')));  

  }
```

Comment: Does this hook get invoked when ie. a comment is added with ajax ie. ajax_comments module which uses ajax to add comments.

Answer (score -2):

There are lots of hooks are available for node.

You can inherit in template.php file and write down your code.

you can use hook_node_update in template.php

Comment: hooks should be used in .module files and not in template.php. Maybe you're confusing them with function template_something. Ex: [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7.x) which goes in your template.php file.